# Add new data to embedded documents in mongodb

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I've been surfing on SO and I haven't found the answer (some similars) for my question, so here I am asking. I'm working with mongodb and php since 2 weeks and I have a database which I want to add new data to one of the embedded/nested documents, but I haven't been able.

This is what I have so far.

```
{    
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab0dc4fb57dce17e0002c5c"),
    "meter" : "meter_2",
    "data" : {
        "magnitude1" : {
            "date" : "05/03/2013 08:13:18",
            "value" : 200
        },
        "magnitude2" : {
            "date" : "30/06/2014 23:46:05",
            "value" : 126
        }
    }
}
```

And now, I' trying to add new data to the subdocument `magnitude`. Something like this:

```
{    
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab0dc4fb57dce17e0002c5c"),
    "meter" : "meter_2",
    "data" : {
        "magnitude1" : {
            "date" : "05/03/2013 08:13:18",
            "value" : 200,
            "somedata" : "somevalue"
        },
    }
}
```

I've tried many things as this one below, but clearly it doesn't gonna insert any data.

```
$center->updateOne(
    ['_id' => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID('5ab0dc4fb57dce17e0002c5c'), 'data.magnitude1'],
    ['$set' => ['somedata' => 'somevalue']]
);
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Try `$center->updateOne(     ['_id' => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID('5ab0dc4fb57dce17e0002c5c')],     ['$set' => ['data.magnitude1.somedata' => 'somevalue']] );`

Comment: @Veeram It works! thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Veeram this question has been solved. Below is the answer in case someone in the future could find it useful.

```
$center->updateOne(
    ['_id' => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID('5ab0dc4fb57dce17e0002c5c')],
    ['$set' => ['data.magnitude1.somedata' => 'somevalue']]
);
```